# Jersey Post request - How to perform a file upload with an unknown number of additional parameters?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I asked something like this previously, but upon re-reading my original post, it was not easy to understand what I was really asking. I have the following situation. We have (or at least I'm trying to get working) a custom file upload procedure that will take in the file, a set number of 'known' metadata values (and they will always be there), as well as potentially an unknown number of additional metadata values. The service that exists currently uses the Jersey framework (1.16)

I currently have both client and server code that handles dealing with the file upload portion and the known metadata values (server code below)

```
@POST
@Path("asset/{obfuscatedValue0}/")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public UUID uploadBlob(@PathParam("obfuscatedValue0") Integer obfuscatedValue0,
    @FormDataParam("obfuscatedValue1") String obfuscatedValue1, 
    @FormDataParam("obfuscatedValue2") String obfuscatedValue2, 
    @FormDataParam("obfuscatedValue3") String obfuscatedValue3,
    @FormDataParam("obfuscatedValue4") String obfuscatedValue4, 
    @FormDataParam("obfuscatedValue5") String obfuscatedValue5,
    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) {
.....
}
```

...and excerpt of client code:

```
Builder requestBuilder = _storageService
.path("asset")
.path(obfuscatedValue0.toString())
.type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

FormDataMultiPart part = new FormDataMultiPart()
.field("file", is, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE) // 'is' is an inputstream from earlier in code.
.field("obfuscatedValue1", obfuscatedValue1)
.field("obfuscatedValue2", obfuscatedValue2)
.field("obfuscatedValue3", obfuscatedValue3)
.field("obfuscatedValue4", obfuscatedValue4)
.field("obfuscatedValue5", obfuscatedValue5);

storedAsset = requestBuilder.post(UUID.class, part);
```

However, I need to pass a map of additional parameters that will have an unknown number of values/names. From what I've seen, there is no easy way to do this using the FormDataParam annotation like my previous example.

Based upon various internet searches related to Jersey file uploads, I've attempted to convert it to use MultivaluedMap with the content type set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" so it resembles this:

```
@POST
@Path("asset/{value}/")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public UUID uploadBlob(@PathParam(value), MultivaluedMap<String,String> formParams) {
....
}
```

It's my understanding that MultivaluedMap is intended to obtain a general map of form parameters (and as such, cannot play nicely together in the same method bearing @FormDataParam annotations.) If I can pass all this information from the Client inside some sort of map, I think I can figure out how to handle parsing the map to grab and 'doMagic()' on the data to get what I want done; I don't think I'll have a problem there.

What I **AM** fairly confused about is how to format the request client-side code when using this second method within the jersey framework. Can anyone provide some guidance for the situation, or some suggestions on how to proceed? I'm considering trying the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413608/sending-list-map-as-post-parameter-jersey) and developing a custom xml adapter to deal with this situation, and sending xml instead of multipart-form-data but I'm still confused how this would interact with the InputStream value that will need to be passed. It appears the examples with MultivaluedMap that I've seen only deal with String data.