# How to set multiple header key value pair in java for jersy client?

Tags: rest

In my test code, I need to send request using jersy client 2.7 in java.
I need to set multiple headers of the web request. e.g.

Header1 12

Header2 abc

In my current working implementation the request is getting formed as mentioned below.
Wherein I am only setting the Authorization token in header using function

```
public void setAuthorizationToken(String authorizationToken) {

        this.token = authorizationToken;

    }


response = webResource.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)                          .header("Authorization", this.token).post(Entity.entity(jsonString, mediaType));
```

I checked that there is a method 
headers (MultiValuedMap < String,Object > headers) to set multiple header KV pairs.

But did not get how to use it.

I have to set the header key value pair from some other function (say setHeader())
 to add more headers in this request as mentioned above.

Can someone please let me know how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can set header value like :


ClientResponse response = resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .header("headerKey1", headerValue1)
                    .header("headerKey2", headerValue2)
                    .header("headerKey3", headerValue3)
                    .post(ClientResponse.class, otherRequestData);


And in service :

String headerValue1= request.getHeader("headerKey1");
String headerValue2= request.getHeader("headerKey2");
String headerValue3= request.getHeader("headerKey3");
```

Comment: But the number of headers can be different in different requests. One request can have only auth token,another can have one or more header along with auth token.so I can not use .header as it is dynamic.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413608/sending-list-map-as-post-parameter-jersey) , it could help you if not please explain a little bit more the requirement.