# unable to pass map to restful method

Tags: java, ajax, rest, post, postman

I am trying to call this API via postman:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void printDetails(final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {

    for(String key : formParams.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + "     " + formParams.get(key));
    }
}
```

But the map turns out to be empty. Please help me with the same.

PS: This is the first time I am trying to pass variable number of parameters to the api. I have referred to 
[sending List/Map as POST parameter jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413608/sending-list-map-as-post-parameter-jersey) and [How to access parameters in a RESTful POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194408/how-to-access-parameters-in-a-restful-post-method).

I think my mistake is in the way I am passing the parameters in postman: [postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqukK.png)

Please help me with the same. Also please help with how to call this API via an ajax (in JS) call.

Comment: I am wondering whether the answer was helpful? Please let me know if it doesn't and what you get after trying this solution, so that I can look at it and resolve.

Comment: @notionquest Sorry for the late reply. I just tried your answer. Unfortunately it also gave me an empty map!

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue or managed to find a solution?

Comment: @notionquest i have found one possible solution. Refer to my answer below. Thank you for trying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out one possible answer.

```
@POST
public void printDetails() {
    HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
    Map<String, String[]> mapp =  request.getParameterMap();
    for(String key : mapp.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key + "     " + mapp.get(key)[0]);
    }
}
```

Still not sure how to do it by passing "final MultivaluedMap" in the arguments

Answer (score 2):

Set the request header as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

[image: Postman request header]

Request body - Select raw and provide values as mentioned below:-

```
{
    "LOCATION": "Singapore"
}
```

[image]