# JSON Map<String,ArrayList> data is not converting into bean object in restful jersey

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jersey

There is a Ajax call with JSON data of String, Array and Map. I am able to get String and Array data after converting into `DashboardChartData` (a Bean class) in jersey but not able to get Map values.
suppose bean is the object of `DashboardChartData` and globalInFilters is a data member of DashboardChartData Class and make setter/getter as same  then
 bean.getGlobalInFilters(); is getting null not desired value.

Code is:

```
        function demo(){
           var dashbord = {
          "aoId": "M_AO_918",
          "viewBys": ["Brand", "Category", "State"],
          "viewIds": ["615228", "615128", "614847"],
          "dimensions": ["615228"],
          "aggregation": ["SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SUM"],
          "meassures": ["Gross Sales", "Net Sales", "Discount Amt", "Discount%",  "Net Margin Amt", "Gross Margin Amt"],
          "meassureIds": ["616275", "616283", "616279", "616648", "616295", "616303"],
          "globalInFilters": {"615228": ["Lenovo", "Apple"]}
                        };

                        $("#query").html(JSON.stringify(dashbord));
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charSet=UTF-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: JSON.stringify(dashbord),
                            url: "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/webresources/solrservice/test1",
                             success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert('Bean created successfully');

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert('Bean error: ' + textStatus);
                }
                        });
            }
```

I have created `DashboardChartData` class with above parameter including:

```
    private Map<String, List<String>> globalInFilters;

  public Map<String, List<String>> getGlobalInFilters() {
        return globalInFilters;
    }

    public void setGlobalInFilters(Map<String, List<String>> globalInFilters) {
        this.globalInFilters = globalInFilters;
    }


         @Path("/test1")
            @POST
            @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            public void setData1(DashboardChartDataBean bean) throws Exception {
                bean.getGlobalInFilters(); //getting null 
                 ProgenSolrDao daoObj = new ProgenSolrDao();

                try {
                    QueryResponse response = daoObj.executeSolrQuery("city",bean);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
```

`bean.getGlobalInFilters()` gets `null`, except this all other values is getting fine. please help how I can get the values of `globalInFilters`.

Comment: I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413608/sending-list-map-as-post-parameter-jersey is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you stringifying before sending it. Try without stringify.

Comment: Its needed otherwise its not calling resource method 'test1'

Comment: Then add @Consumes("application/json") in your REST Api and try

Comment: @Consumes("application/json")  is also not working still getting null