# Create HashMap<String,Map> from List < Map<String,Object>> gives java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, list, hashmap, iteration, classcastexception

Below is my code.Any help is appreciated.
I am simply not able to read list and create a Map.
I am passing a `List<Map<String, Object>>` as a 
function parameter till the Rest layer.In Rest Proxy call its a
plain List. In my service layer I need to use Map values stored in the List.

My List has values as mentioned

```
[{ID=56, VALUE=CPR,DESCRIPTOR=HEAD}, 
{ID=68,VALUE=RegFinance,DESCRIPTOR=FINANCE}]
```

I want a create `Map<String,Map> using List<Map<String, Object>>` in below format

```
{56={ID=56, VALUE=CPR,DESCRIPTOR=HEAD}, 
68={ID=68,VALUE=RegFinance,DESCRIPTOR=FINANCE}}
```

Below code works before rest call is made i.e in Controller layer but does not work in Service layer after rest call.

```
    Map<String, Object> userRoleMap = new HashMap<>();
                for (int count = 0; count < allRolesDetails.size(); count++) {
                    //Map<String, Object> mapp=allRolesDetails.get(count);
                   //Above line Gives Exception

                    String[] singleColumn = allRolesDetails.get(count).toString().split(",");
                   //Above line Gives Exception

                    for(String pair : singleColumn)  
                    {
                        String[] entry = pair.split("=");   
                        userRoleMap.put(entry[1].trim(),allRolesDetails.get(count)); 
                        break;//add them to the hashmap and trim whitespaces
                    }
                }
```

Tried all other options on StackoverFlow

```
Iterator<Map<String, Object>> it = allRolesDetails.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = it.next(); //so here you don't need a potentially unsafe cast
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
```

And

```
for(Map<String, Object> map:allRolesDetails){
                for(Map.Entry<String, Object>entry : map.entrySet()){
                    String Key=entry.getKey();
                    Object Value=entry.getValue();
                }
            }
```

In all the cases I am getting the below exception whenever I am using `allRolesDetails.get(count)` or trying to user Iterator or Map.Entry.

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you have two maps ?

Comment: Yes  one is Empty Map userRoleMap<String,Map> in which I want to fill values from List<Map<String,Object>>

Answer (score 1):

You are typing a LOT of code here, when you could just do this

```java
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> userRoleMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map<String, Object> m : allRolesDetails) {
    userRoleMap.put(m.get("ID"), m);
}
```

Comment: Still gives me below exception   at           for (Map<String, Object> m : allRolesDetails) {                                                   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map
 at com.apple.sfo.workflow.service.InventoryServiceImpl.fetchCenterForDetails(InventoryServiceImpl.java:4649)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: After I figured out the problem used above few lines of code instead of a LOT of code which I was using.Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
As I mentioned

> Below code works before rest call is made i.e in Controller layer but
>   does not work in Service layer after rest call.

There was an Issue with type of parameter I was passing in RestProxy Call
I was passing `@QueryParam(value = "allRolesDetails") List allRolesDetails`  instead of `final List<Map<String, Object>>  allRolesDetails` .After this change proper Map was getting retrieved while iterating List.
This post helped me find my problem.
[sending List/Map as POST parameter jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413608/sending-list-map-as-post-parameter-jersey)