# JAX-RS Mixing @FormParam and MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams

Tags: java, rest, annotations, jersey, jax-rs

I've a method that returns all records sons of a father record (document and rows for example):

```
public Datasource<Son> getSonsFromParent( @FormParam(value = "idparent") Long idparent,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) throws Exception;
```

I've a well known parameter, "idparent". I want to get this parameter simply using `@FormParam` . It's useful for exposing this method to other people: they know that a "idparent" is required.

Also, I have a number of undefined parameters for sorting and filtering my datasource, for example

```
 sort[0]=name

  sort[1]=surname

  filter[0][field]=name

  filter[0][operator]=equal

  filter[0][value]=Marc
```

The problem is : **using `@FormParam`, the multivalue map is always empty.**

How can i mix MultivaluedMap and `@FormParam` together ?

Comment: Take a look here. It is an answer that can fit your needs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413608/sending-list-map-as-post-parameter-jersey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `@Formparam, MultiValuedMap, @FormDataParam,@BeanParam` in the same *resource method*. JAX-RS wouldn't  know which is the proper object to map the info comming in the request.

In any case, I don't see why you don't just use `MultiValuedMap<String,String> formParams` and just **validate** `idParent`.

Using  `@Formparam` **doesn't** make such parameter **required**, you're in charge of this through your code implementation:

```
public Datasource<Son> getSonsFromParent( MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {

  String idParent = formParams.getFirst("idparent");

  if(idParent == null || idParent.isEmpty()){
     // return .... [idParent is required] 400 Bad Request
  }
}
```

If you mean to expose such parameter to your clients, it also means that your documentation for this API **will expose all** of the parameters, not only the required one right ?

Comment: I'd like to use @FormParam because it cast String to Long if my param is an integer. after that i'll check if(param == null) throw exception.
FormParam was only a simpler way, but if i can't use it, i can't :) Thank you