# Idiom to handle post forms with hash maps (key/value pairs)

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

Using fields with the same name in a POST form allows to obtain request values right into a `List<String>` variable:

```
<input name="colors" value="white">
<input name="colors" value="black">
```

Is there a similar idiomatic mechanism to handle key / value pairs?

I tried different random syntaxes in the `name` attribute and none triggered the same magic as my previous example so I figured out I could always invent mine. However this:

```
<input name="colors[background]" value="white">
<input name="colors[foreground]" value="blacks">
```

... causes the field to be missing from `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getParameter()`:

```
// None work
request.getParameter("colors")
request.getParameter("colors[background]")
```

This suggests square brackets have a special meaning anyway, albeit not the one I expected.

How should I handle my `Hash` variables? I'm using Jdeveloper 11g, WebLogic 10.3 and Jersey 1.17 in case there's an implementation extension not mandated by JAX-RS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sending List/Map as POST parameter jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413608/sending-list-map-as-post-parameter-jersey)

Comment: @DaveWebb In that question they use Jersey as client rather than having an HTML form so it's unclear what the `name` attribute should be. Also, form params are captured as method arguments rather than grabbing them from `HttpServletRequest`. I could rewrite my app that way but I'd like to know for sure whether it's necessary.